# Cannot access wamp server on local network

Tags: apache, wamp

I want to host a website on my local network. For some reason I can only access wamp in my local computer.

I have 2 computers in my network. Both computer A and computer B have wamp server installed. when I type the ip address of computer A from computer B I am able to connect to it. But when I do it the other way around it does not work! In other words when I type the ip address of computer B from computer A the browsers says: server at 192.168.0.120 is taking to long to respond.

Things that I have done in order to solve the problem on computer B: (remember I want to connect to computer B from computer A)

1) turn off the firewall

2) Uninstall wamp and reinstall it.

3) turn off the anti-virus.

4) turn off windows firewall

5) Place wamp online and after putting it online restart all services

### after doing all those steps I still cannot connect to it from computer B!

I have not chaged any ini file plus I have uninstall it and install it again so why is it not possible to connect to it!? I have used wamp for the last 3 years and I have never experienced this.

Also wamp is the only web server that I have installed on this computer. I don't have IIS nor any other web server installed on my computer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Perhaps your Apache is bounded to localhost only. Look in your apache configuration file for:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

If you found it, replace it with:

```
Listen 80
```

Then restart Apache.

[(More info about Apache Binding)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html)

Comment: It has Listen 80. Thanks now I know how to change the port. I changed it to:  Listen 1234   and now I see my wamp server by going to http://localhost:1234/   but I am still not able to access that webserver from computer A when I type http://192.168.0.120:1234/

Comment: But anyways I uninstall wamp and installed again so I guess it has to be a problem with the computer. I am about to uninstall the anti-virus. this is really strange...

Comment: I would add that a restart is required (although that applies to any apache config changes). Likely too late @Tono, but for any new visitors port 80 is the (by default) external facing port. Replacing it for an arbitrary port won't always work, because that port may not be open to the network.

Answer (score 19):

**Turn off your firewall** for port 80 from any address. Turn off 443 if you need https (SSL) access. Open the configuration file (`http.conf`) and find the lines that say:

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Change them to read

```
Allow from all
```

Restart the wampserver. It will now work. Enjoy!!

Comment: no lines with allow from

Answer (score 8):

**1.**

first of all
Port 80(or what ever you are using) and 443 must be allow for both TCP and UDP packets. To do this, create 2 inbound rules for TPC and UDP on Windows Firewall for port 80 and 443.
(or you can disable your whole firewall for testing but permanent solution if allow inbound rule)

**2.**

#### If you are using WAMPServer 3 See bottom of answer

#### For WAMPServer versions <= 2.5

You need to change the security setting on Apache to allow access from anywhere else, so edit your `httpd.conf` file.

Change this section from :

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from localhost
```

To :

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from all
```

if "Allow from all" line not work for your then use "Require all granted"
then it will work for you.

#### WAMPServer 3 has a different method

In version 3 and > of WAMPServer there is a Virtual Hosts pre defined for `localhost` so dont amend the `httpd.conf` file at all, leave it as you found it.

Using the menus, edit the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

[image]

It should look like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Amend it to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note:if you are running wamp for other than port 80 then VirtualHost will be like VirtualHost *:86.(86 or port whatever you are using) instead of VirtualHost *:80

**3.**
**Dont forget to restart All Services of Wamp or Apache after making this change**

Answer (score 6):

go Setting -> General and change url in WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL)

enter your pc name or your ip address in place of localhost

before : `http://localhost/wordpress-test`

after : `http://your-pc-name/wordpress-test`

...and that's it..you can access wordpress from any pc in your LAN...!!!

Comment: You are a life saver took me hours to find this solution. Are you able to provide direction to any texts explaining why use of local ip addresses  does not work when accessing another computer in the LAN?

Answer (score 2):

Wamp server share in local network

Reference Link: http://forum.aminfocraft.com/blog/view/141/wamp-server-share-in-local-netword

Edit your Apache httpd.conf:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
#Deny from all
```

and

```
#onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
#Deny from all
```

---

to share mysql server:

edit wamp/alias/phpmyadmin.conf

```
<Directory "E:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.2.0.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    #Deny from all
    Allow from all
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, tried all nothing works, following works for me

Following is what i had

```
#onlineoffline tag - don't remove

Require local
```

Change to

```
Require all granted
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
```

Comment: So basically anyone who wants to access your server is allowed to... great idea.

Comment: NOTE: `Require all granted` is Apache 2.4 syntax and `Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all` is Apache 2.2 syntax. **You should not**, and should not need to use both in the same `httpd.conf`

Answer (score 1):

I had to uninstall my anti virus! Before uninstalling I clicked on the option where it said to disable auto-protect for 15 min. I also clicked on another option that supposibly disabled the anti-virus. That still was blocking my server! I don't understand why Norton makes it so hard to literally stop doing everything it's doing. I know I could had solve it by adding an exception to the firewall but Norton was taking care of windows firewall as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post BUT I have been having problems getting WAMP server seen on my windows 7 pro network for days, tried all of the solutions offered (including changing windows system files) but still not working. finally in pure desperation I put everything on the system back as it was and installed WAMP Server on a different drive (E:\WAMP ) in my case. The result was it worked perfectly first time with no editing configs or messing with the system. Other users may wish to try this before reaching the 'tear your hair out stage', it certainly saved my sanity or what I have left of it
I hope this helps someone
Dave

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wamp stack, it will be fixed by open port in Firewall (Control Pannel). It work for my case (detail how to open port 80: https://tips.alocentral.com/open-tcp-port-80-in-windows-firewall/)

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem but mine worked fine. Turn off your firewall, antivirus. Make sure your port 80 is enabled and both pcs are set to be remotely accessed. In each pc under users, add new user using the host ip address of the other pc. Restart all services. Put your wampserver online. It should connect