# WAMP Cannot access on local network 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wampserver

I know this question has been asked a lot of times

I followed Most of the answers in the internet But I still get the same Message

> 403 Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

It is weird that when I access using the same PC to **`localhost:1234`** it runs normally but if I access using my IP address **`192.168.0.188:1234`**

Also which is really weird is that I tried to install WAMP on other PC and without any configuration I could access to that PC.

So I thought it's because McAfee and Firewall so I open port on Widows and McAfee and nothing changed also I turned off Firewall and still nothing change.

Then for no reason I opened  port through the Router “port forwarding” and still nothing changed.

I don't think that it's because my configuration in WAMP since I am still able to get this `403 Forbidden` Message and also by using other PC without any configuration I could access it.

***Both PCs are setup like this:***

**Windows 8 Pro**

- **WAMP Wampserver:** 2.4
- **Apache Version:** 2.4.4
- **PHP Version:** 5.4.12
- **MySQL Version:** 5.6.12

The accessible PC uses *Microsoft Security Essentials*.

The inaccessible PC uses *McAfee Internet Security*.

I tried to turn **off WAMP** and **start IIS** For Microsoft Server (I works perfectly From any PC) but WAMP is still not not working

I followed these tutorial:

- [How to Access WAMP Server in LAN or WAN](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/395286/How-to-Access-WAMP-Server-in-LAN-or-WAN)
- [Install & Setup Virtual Host Guide for WAMP](http://guides.jlbn.net/setvh/setvh1.html)
- [Install & Setup LAN & Worldwide Access Guide for WAMP](http://guides.jlbn.net/setaccess/setaccess1.html)

And the Stack Overflow answers here:

- [Cannot access wamp server on local network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219062/cannot-access-wamp-server-on-local-network)
- [WAMP 403 Forbidden message on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204902/wamp-403-forbidden-message-on-windows-7)

Comment: Do you have any proxy settings on your browser?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

#### If you are using WAMPServer 3 See bottom of answer

#### For WAMPServer versions <= 2.5

By default Wampserver comes configured as securely as it can, so Apache is set to only allow access from the machine running wamp. Afterall it is supposed to be a *development* server and *not* a live server.

Also there was a little error released with WAMPServer 2.4 where it used the old Apache 2.2 syntax instead of the new Apache 2.4 syntax for access rights.

You need to change the security setting on Apache to allow access from anywhere else, so edit your `httpd.conf` file.

Change this section from :

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from localhost
```

To :

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require local
    Require ip 192.168.0
```

The `Require local` allows access from these ip's `127.0.0.1 & localhost & ::1`.

The statement `Require ip 192.168.0` will allow you to access the Apache server from any ip on your internal network. Also it will allow access using the server mechines actual ip address from the server machine, as you are trying to do.

#### WAMPServer 3 has a different method

In version 3 and > of WAMPServer there is a Virtual Hosts pre defined for `localhost` so you have to make the access privilage amendements in the Virtual Host definition config file

First dont amend the `httpd.conf` file at all, leave it as you found it.

Using the menus, edit the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

[image]

It should look like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Amend it to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hopefully you will have created a Virtual Host for your project and not be using the `wamp\www` folder for your site. In that case leave the localhost definition alone and make the change only to your Virtual Host.

**Dont forget to restart Apache after making this change**

Comment: @RiggsFolly But I can not access the site on my phone in the wireless network with address of 127.0.0.1 though. Anything I did wrong?

Comment: @Chen What is the ip address of your PC running the Apache server?

Comment: Just in case your wamp menu doesn't have the httpd-vhosts.conf option you can still get it in the following location "C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf"

Comment: @IWantAnswers In that case [upgrade to latest V3.1.1 of WAMPServer or whatever is the latest](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/). This is an inplace upgrade and only updates the WAMPServer code and NOT any AMP components or web site code

Answer (score 31):

For Apache 2.4.9

in addition, look at the **httpd-vhosts.conf** file in C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost
DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Require local
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Change to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost
DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

changing from "Require **local**" to "Require **all granted**" solved the error 403 in my local network

Comment: This solved it for me, after trying everything else. In my opinion this should automatically be done by the "Put Online" button of the WampManager.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos The `Put Online` funtion is now deprecated, and not on the menu by default for that reason.

Answer (score 18):

I got this answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219062/cannot-access-wamp-server-on-local-network). and its works for me

```
Require local
```

Change to

```
Require all granted
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
```

Comment: Except that `Require all granted` is Apache 2.4 syntax, and `Order Deny,Allow Allow from all` is Apache 2.2 syntax. Now as long as you have the compat module loaded you can use either. However using **both** is just going to confuse Apache

Comment: But now I can only see localhost page. When I jump on phpmyadmin or to my project directory it changes the URL to localhost.  It says site can't be reach. Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 9):

To expand on [RiggsFolly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382627/wamp-cannot-access-on-local-network-403-forbidden/23385021#23385021)’s answer—or for anyone who is facing the same issue but is using Apache 2.2 or below—this format should work well:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
Allow from localhost
Allow from 192.168
Allow from 10
Satisfy Any
```

For more details on the format changes for Apache 2.4, the official [Upgrading to 2.2 from 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html) page is pretty clear & concise. Key point being:

> The old access control idioms should be replaced by the new
>   authentication mechanisms, although for compatibility with old
>   configurations, the new module `mod_access_compat` is provided.

Which means, system admins around the world don’t necessarily have to panic about changing Apache 2.2 configs to be 2.4 compliant just yet.

Comment: @JakeGould, Thank you, fried my brain searching for this answer. :)

Comment: Thank you, this is the working config I use for WampServer 2.2

Answer (score 3):

**For those who may be running WAMP 3.1.4 with Apache 2.4.35 on Windows 10 (64-bit)**

If you're having issues with external devices connecting to your localhost, and receiving a 403 Forbidden error, it may be an issue with your *httpd.conf* and the *httpd-vhosts.conf* files and the "Require local" line they both have within them.

***[Before] httpd-vhosts.conf***

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost
 ServerAlias localhost
 DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
 <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
   Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Require local     <--- This is the offending line.
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

***[After] httpd-vhosts.conf***

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost
 ServerAlias localhost
 DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
 <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
   Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Additionally, you'll need to update your **httpd.conf** file as follows:

**[Before] httpd.conf**

```
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove

    Require local  #<--- This is the offending line.
</Directory>
```

**[After] httpd.conf**

```
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove

#   Require local
</Directory>
```

Make sure to restart your WAMP server via (System tray at bottom-right of screen --> left-click WAMP icon --> "Restart all Services").

Then refresh your machine's browser on localhost to ensure you've still got proper connectivity there, and then refresh your other external devices that you were previously attempting to connect.

**Disclaimer:** If you're in a corporate setting, this is untested from a security perspective; please ensure you're keenly aware of your local development environment's access protocols before implementing any sweeping changes.