# How to access wamp from other networks?

Tags: php, sql, apache, wamp, remote-access

I'm trying to access WAMP from another network and the server is not responding. I have configured WAMP to be accessed on the LAN and it works fine.

Now I want to make my WAMP accessible through other networks on a remote PC.

I tried to search online but couldn't find any answers regarding this nor any videos.

Is it even possible, and if yes then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to access wamp server publically.

1. Both of the machine(the server and the client) must be connected to the internet.
2. Enable permission in wamp to access from other network. A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23382627/3049065) is available how to give permission to access wamp apache from other network. check that.
3. If you using datacard or using mobile means you are the direct server. So you can able to access the wamp server directly using your public ip address. To get public ip follow this [link](http://www.getip.com/).
4. If you are using router means you need to enable port forwarding. Because the public ip is not directly assigned to you system. You'll get only local ip. The public ip is assigned to your router only. So you need to tell router to send the http request to your server using portforwarding to your local ip. Major routers support this facility. Check the respected router manual to enable portforwarding. For linksys router use this [link](http://www.linksys.com/ca/support-article?articleNum=136711). After enable portforwarding get the public of your network using this [link](http://www.getip.com/). Now when you access your public ip means the router will forward those request to your system.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/822902/3049065) for xampp is available. check that too.

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: While configuring my port forwarding i get this error. "The requested URL /advanced/adv_nat_dmz.htm was not found on this server."

Comment: heyy!!! i tried this and it worked but with a glitch.... when i type in my public ip it shows my wamp homepage.. thats good.... but when i try to access it from other network it does not open. so do i need to do anything else???

Comment: im using my cellular network as a different network to log in

Comment: im sorry im still new to this...... actually there is no content i need to access from my localhost... just my wamp homepage and phpmyadmin.... i have the access via lan but on trying with other network i m not able to access it.... i just want to redirect everyone who accesses my ip to my localhost.... i read certain answers about configuring vhosts... but i dont think i need that...

Comment: if you getting the wamp page using that ip means it is connected to the system. Now you need to route them using virtualhost file only. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: heyy mahendran.... thank you very much sir... idk why but this problem has something to do with refreshing... once i refreshed my router settings it started working on its own,.. no extra configuration was needed....

Comment: If the above answer solves your question means mark it as the answer using the tick mark below the voting functionality and upvote the answer.

Comment: any number of user can able access that. but the response time will based on server internet speed.

Comment: yes but one condition if another user want hosting their wamp server means he need to use it in another port in port forwarding. not able to use same port for different user. if you are using 80 means a new user need to use another port like 81 or whatever(0-65536). But don't use another default application ports. It ll lead to conflict. To access the new users server you need to use `http://ip-address:portno`.(ex: if you are forward 9000 port to the new users wamp server means you can access the server using `http://111.111.111.111:9000`).

Answer (score 0):

You want your own computer to act like a web server. WAMP works fine as a web server but you need to make sure others know about your IP address. See what is your public IP and try to access your WAMP over that IP.

Comment: it opens my router config page

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dedicated connection, then all you have to do is change your firewall settings to allow incoming remote connections.

Also use the Put Online option of your WAMP Server and you can use this current system IP address and to directly access from the other computer.
See below:

[image]