# connect to local machine from iphone

Tags: php, ios, permissions, localhost

I am trying to connect my iPhone to a web service on my Macs local machine.

On the Mac I can go to `localhost/~username` and i get "My Site Works"

On the iPhone I go to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` (Macs IP Address) and I get "It Works!" but when I go to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~username` I get Forbidden - You do not have permission to access `/~username` on the server

Both devices are on the same *Wi-Fi* network

This is Mac OS X, Please don't link to solutions for Windows. I'm a Total Noob

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WAMP Cannot access on local network 403 Forbidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382627/wamp-cannot-access-on-local-network-403-forbidden)

Comment: That solution is for Windows. I'm on OS X

Comment: You have to alter the `httpd.conf`file... it has nothing to do with the OS.. It's a file in apache.

Comment: I have looked through the tutorial and I don't have a `#   onlineoffline tag`

is the below the same? 
`# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
   AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>`

Comment: Yeah, that is the problem. Make it: AllowOverride all Require all inside the Directory tag.

Comment: have completed the below, still getting forbidden

Comment: Used sudo apachectl -k restart and got
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Jamess-Mac-Mini.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Still getting forbidden

Comment: ServerName must be localhost or a domain name..

Comment: that cleared the warning up but still getting forbidden on the device :(

Comment: Fixed it. Had a custom username.conf where I had require set to local, not all

Answer (score 0):

Open Settings on your Mac, go to Sharing, enable file sharing, add your users folder to shared folders and allow everybody to access the resource.