# 403 Forbidden error on Genymotion

Tags: php, wamp, genymotion

I installed genymotion emulator on my PC and I want to access my WAMP local server to it and I ran `ipconfig` on my `cmd` so I got this IP_address `192.168.56.1` but the problem is that I always get this error

> 403 Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access / on this server

I tried all the answers given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382627/wamp-cannot-access-on-local-network-403-forbidden) yet none solved my problem.

I am running 
Mysql 5.5.8,
PHP 5.3.5 and
Apache 2.2.17

Please do anyone know how I can fix this error?

@KANAYOAUSTINKANE. This is my code or the Subdomain

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/mobile"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias m.local host
</Virtualhost>
```

Please help me out, I have been so disturbed

Comment: can you view that url in a browser, outside genymotion?

Comment: No all browser still gives me the same error. Chrome, Firefox, opera

Comment: Are you trying a mobile site? If yes then did you create any virtual host or Subdomain for your mobile site or you still use the `localhost` if you did create a virtual host then I would love to see your httpd-vhost.conf file for the virtual host because I think I have found your answer

Comment: Yes I did. I will edit my question to show my code

Comment: @TheKingis then the problem is the wamp setup and has nothing to do with genymotion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is a solution.

**First step**

Change the location of your virtual host and add a `/` at the end like this

```
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/mobile/"
```

**Second step**

Go to your `httpd.conf` file located at `C:/camp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.17/conf/httpd.conf` the go to the line that has `Listen 80` and change it to `Listen *:80` this will make it to listen to any IP address

**Finally**

You go to the end of your `httpd.conf` file and add this

```
# Tells Apache to identify which site by name
NameVirtualHost *:80
# Tells Apache to serve the default WAMP Server page to "localhost"
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
</VirtualHost> 
# Tells Apache to serve your mobile pages to "m.localhost"
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
# The name to respond to ServerName m.localhost
# Folder where the file is located which in your case is
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/mobile/"
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/mobile/">
    Allow from all
    Order Allow,Deny
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
# Apache will look for these files, in this order, if no file is specified in the URL, but you can add more files apart from the two I listed depending on what you are having
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost> 
#Here you duplicate the code for your mobile site to also accept your IP address which is 192.168.56.1
<VirtualHost 192.168.56.1>
# The name to respond to ServerName m.localhost
# Folder where the file is located which in your case is
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/mobile/"
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/mobile/">
    Allow from all
    Order Allow,Deny
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
# Apache will look for these files, in this order, if no file is specified in the URL, but you can add more files apart from the two I listed depending on what you are having
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Tested and working. Please don't forget to mark the answer

Comment: Thanks very much. Your answer is great and perfect, it solved my problem perfectly. :)