# Error HTTP 403 Forbidden Access in WAMP server

Tags: apache, wampserver

I'm trying to access a page on WAMP server 3.0.4 from a different computer on the same network, but I get the error HTTP 403

```html
<pre>
Error: HTTP 403
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /Test/index.html
on this server.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Win64) PHP/5.6.19 Server at 192.168.1.30 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
</pre>
```

I know this question has been asked before and I have followed the answers given in these previous questions but I still get the same error. Maybe the syntax in WAMP 3 is different? One clear difference is that at least now there is no "put online" button in the tray.

I have tried

1. switching off both windows firewall and antivirus (bullguard) firewall.
2. In the httpd.conf file changed the server name to my ip address

   ServerName 192.168.1.30:80
3. Changed the onlineoffline tag e.g.

```
    onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require local
    require ip 192.168.1
```

In general I have modified the httpd.conf following all answers I've found including but not limited to 
[WAMP Cannot access on local network 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382627/wamp-cannot-access-on-local-network-403-forbidden)

but there's still no solution.

The complete file can be found here

[httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/2yG5dXrx)

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Really not sure but, try require ip 192.168.0 instead of .1

Comment: @MarcGiroux  still no luck

Comment: I've removed both PHP and MySQL tags from your question. They have absolutely nothing to do with it. Don't use "popular" tags just to get extra attention to your question.

Comment: @Girauder, did you restart the server after changing the configuration?

Comment: @dekel yeah I did

Comment: @icecube sorry that was not my intension, I only used the tags that were used in the other questions that I found

Comment: Check [this answer again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382627/wamp-cannot-access-on-local-network-403-forbidden) I have amended it for WAMPServer3> versions

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you so much, it is now working! . The only difference with wath you post there is that for me, I couldn't see the httpd-vhosts.conf file where you mention, but can be found here: **C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.18\conf\extra**. If you make it into an answer I'll mark this question as solved. Otherwise thank you so much again.

Comment: Just give the other answer an upvote if it helped you. We try and keep duplicates down to a minimum here if possible