# Wamp server is not accessible from other PC

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I am using
Wampserver 3.0.4 having
Apache 2.4.18 - PHP 5.6.19 - MySQL 5.7.11

As I am using wampserver>=3. So I have followed all the steps as given on
[WAMP Cannot access on local network 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382627/wamp-cannot-access-on-local-network-403-forbidden).
But even after making the changes I am not able to access the server from other computer. 
Here is the content of my **httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:8000>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

httpd.exe -S output:

```
VirtualHost configuration: *:8000 localhost (C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.18/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.c‌​onf:5) 
ServerRoot: "C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.18" 
Main DocumentRoot: "C:/wamp64/www" 
Main ErrorLog: "C:/wamp64/logs/apache_error.log" 
Mutex default: dir="C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.18/logs/" mechanism=default 
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults 
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults 
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults 
PidFile: "C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.18/logs/httpd.pid" 
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS 
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG 
Define: APACHE24=Apache2.4
```

Here is the [http.conf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxhifDelTzILQ2dJODREWWZyUkk/view?usp=sharing) file.

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: Apache Error log:  Client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp64/www/.htaccess.old

Comment: are you trying to access the .htaccess.old file directly? what are you requesting exactly? And show apachectl -S output in your question (edit)

Comment: From other computer I am trying 
http:{My IP}:8000/App.html

Comment: httpd.exe -S output:
VirtualHost configuration:
*:8000  localhost (C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.18/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:5)
ServerRoot: "C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.18"
Main DocumentRoot: "C:/wamp64/www"
Main ErrorLog: "C:/wamp64/logs/apache_error.log"
Mutex default: dir="C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.18/logs/" mechanism=default
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
PidFile: "C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.18/logs/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
Define: APACHE24=Apache2.4

Comment: Try taking the `.htaccess.old` out of that directory. You shoudl not have a `.htaccess` file in the www folder anyway