# Enable local network access to sites on WAMP Server

Tags: apache, networking, wamp, wampserver

I have Windows 10 64 bit,  WampServer Version 3.0.6 64bit,  Apache/2.4.23 (Win64),  PHP/5.6.25.

I have downloaded a fresh version of it today so it is the latest version.

I am trying to make my sites available on the local network.

I have created a virtual host for my site and i am able to access my site properly on my pc (where the server is also located). 
I have tried all below solutions but none of them works

Here is my Httpd.conf

```
Require all granted
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Here is my Httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testsite
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/simple-php-website-master"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/simple-php-website-master/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have put my server online by enabling the options by `Right click Wampmanager -> WAMPSetting -> Menu Item: Online/Offline`

Both antivirus and windows firewall is turned off. I am running it as administrator. Also reinstalling didn't work.

I am using pc ip address to access the site and i have tried all below formats but none of them worked

- 192.168.0.36/testsite/index.php
- 192.168.0.36/testsite/
- 192.168.0.36/

Already looked into following solutions.

- [why wamp server put online/ offline option is missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810669/why-wamp-server-put-online-offline-option-is-missing)
- [How to enable local network users to access my WAMP sites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005828/how-to-enable-local-network-users-to-access-my-wamp-sites)
- [Cannot access wamp server on local network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219062/cannot-access-wamp-server-on-local-network)
- [How to enable local network users to access my WAMP sites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005828/how-to-enable-local-network-users-to-access-my-wamp-sites)

I am using [this simple site](https://github.com/banago/simple-php-website) to test. it doesn't have any database or anything.

I am getting below error when I try to access the site from mobile or any other pc

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /testsite on this server.

Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 Server at 192.168.0.36 Port 80
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this virtualhost don't apply because you wrote :

ServerName testsite

But you try to reach it with 192.168.0.36/testsite

You should try to put in your Virtualhost :
ServerName 192.168.0.36/testsite

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the hosts file in every computer on lan you want access from.

path C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

I recommend using Notepad++ in administrator mode

you will need to add something like this
192.168.0.16    testsite.dev
where the Ip is the local ip address of the computer that is the server
and yes, i would recommend to add a ".dev" to your virtual host, after you modify your virtual host remember to restart the services.