# android app works on emulator but not in real device

Tags: java, android

My app is working fine in `AVD` but when i try to run my app in my mobile it is showing this error. It is not connecting to server. It is not accessing `php` file. I have given path for `php` file is "http://10.0.0.72/myapp/search.php". I'm using `wamp server` and kept my `php` file inside `www` folder.

**Logcat Error**

> java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.0.72 (port 80):
>   connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) 06-13 13:19:20.229
>   13823-14092/com.myapp W/System.err:     at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
>   Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Comment: Must be sure that you are not using URL of your local host.

Comment: try to put your real device on wifi, your server seems to be available only on local network

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378501/how-to-browse-localhost-on-android-device

Comment: (Connection timed out) may be its due to slowness in internet or server.

Comment: Thanks for your response all.....My mobile and my PC are in same wifi network and also i have given internet permissions to my app.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you run your wamp server in local PC. Connect both your phone and PC (which has the wamp server) to the same network and replace 10.0.0.72 with the **private IP of the PC**.
Try the url in the phone browser, It should be accessible. 
Make sure you have given **internet permission** in the manifest file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.....Yes I'm running wamp server in my local PC, and both are connected to same wifi. 10.0.0.72 This is private IP of my PC. I've also given Internet permission in the manifest file but din't get success.

Comment: Are you able to access the file in browser?

Comment: No, I'm not able to access the file in phone browser. It's showing "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT".

Comment: Seems like connection issue. Try with the network created by your phone hotspot. Connect the PC to the hotspot and try with the new IP.

Comment: I tried with different network and new IP but it's showing "ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE". still did't get success.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219062/cannot-access-wamp-server-on-local-network&ved=0ahUKEwjpy_-lnr_UAhWJuI8KHfbPDEcQFgguMAQ&usg=AFQjCNHFk2wMKLJs9sJxHYVM0bHtQngniQ&sig2=g6a4C15EnJhTVlypMoGDBg
Maybe the answers in the link would help. Actually that guy made it work by disabling his antivirus.